# Two-dimensional array: calculate sum of rows and product of columns

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I am currently working on a task which says the following:

> Input a two-dimensional array A (m,n) [m < 10, n < 20]. In the n + 1 column calculate the sum of the rows, and in the m + 1 row the product of the columns. Print out the resulting matrix.

According to my understanding of this task, at the end of each column must be the sum of according rows (so on the right hand side), and the product of the column (at the end/bottom?).

This task is so confusing I do not know where to start. I found some code that covers the idea but does not include the product and it does not display these values as the task asks me to:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int a[3][3];
    int i, j, s = 0, sum = 0;

    cout << "Enter 9 elements of 3*3 Matrix \n";
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cin >> a[i][j];

    cout << "Matrix Entered By you is \n";
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            s = s + a[i][j];
        cout << "sum of" << i + 1 << " Row is" << s;
        s = 0;
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            s = s + a[j][i];
        cout << "sum of" << i + 1 << " Column is" << s;
        s = 0;
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        sum = sum + a[i][i];
    cout << "Sum of Diagnols Elements is \n" << sum;

    getch();
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are having? Operator for calculating product in C++ is `*`. As for displaying values as asked to, you need to declare matrix with additional row at the end, initialize values in that row to 0 and after that instead of printing to stdin put caluclated product values in given index.

Comment: What should the field/cell in the (m + 1)th row and the (n + 1)th column carry?

Comment: @aschipfl (m+1)th - product of columns and (n + 1)th - sum of rows

Comment: Yes, this I understood, but I mean the bottom right cell...

Comment: @aschipfl I dont know. I just suggested that out of my understading. What do you think it should be? Could your perhaps provide some code?

Comment: is there any complexity restriction ?

Comment: @VenuKantSahu not really

Comment: then just create to seperate function to do so with brute force i'm posting a solution ok? just makw your array global it  and call this two function in main

Comment: Bottom right cell:  Ask your instructor if the problem statement is not clear.  (I assume this is homework of some sort).  Personally, I would print a blank there.

Comment: Declare 2 dimensional array and calculate sum of each row in front of same row and product of each column in front of same column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We beginners should help each other.

Here you are

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    const size_t M = 10;
    const size_t N = 20;
    int a[M][N] = {};

    std::cout << "Enter number of rows: (less than " << M << "): ";

    size_t m;

    std::cin >> m;

    if (!(m < M) || (m == 0)) m = M - 1;

    std::cout << "Enter number of columns: (less than " << N << "): ";

    size_t n;

    std::cin >> n;

    if (!(n < N) || (n == 0)) n = N - 1;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter " << n
            << " numbers for the row " << i << ": ";
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++) std::cin >> a[i][j];
    }

    for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++) a[m][j] = 1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            a[i][n] += a[i][j];
            a[m][j] *= a[i][j];
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m + 1; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n + 1; j++)
        {
            std::cout << std::setw(3) << a[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter number of rows: (less than 10): 3
Enter number of columns: (less than 20): 3

Enter 3 numbers for the row 0: 1 2 3
Enter 3 numbers for the row 1: 4 5 6
Enter 3 numbers for the row 2: 7 8 9

  1   2   3   6
  4   5   6  15
  7   8   9  24
 28  80 162   0
```

So you have to declare an array with 10 rows and 20 columns. The user should enter the dimensions of the array that are correspondingly less than 10 and 20. One row and one column are reserved for sums and products.

It is desirable that the array would be initially initialized by zeroes.

```
int a[M][N] = {};
```

In this case you need not to set the last column with zeroes as you have to do with last row initializing it with ones.

That is all.:)

Comment: Don't think much of the error handling when m >= M or n >= N.  You will just overwrite the end of the array.  Printing an error and calling `exit(1);` would be much better.  I also suspect you should check for m < 1 and n < 1.

Comment: @MartinBonner Adding additional messages and exits makes the program more complicated.:) In my opinion such simple programs should have a straightforward logic.

Comment: @MartinBonner Only now I have seen that the variable sum is redundant.:) I have removed it.

Comment: Sorry.  I misread what your test was doing.  (For some reason I inverted the sense of the test, and then read the controlled statement as `m = m-1;` rather than `m = M - 1;`.)  Your actual code is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the declaration: make sure that your program works with m×n matrix, not simply a 3×3 matrix. Since m and n have limits of 10 and 20, and because you must add an extra row and a column to the result, the declaration should be

```
int a[11][21];
```

You also need to declare `m` and `n`, have end-user enter them, and validate them to be within their acceptable ranges:

```
int m, n;
cin >> m >> n;
... // Do the validation
```

Now you can rewrite your loops in terms of `m` and `n`, rather than using `3` throughout your code.

With these declarations in place, you can total the numbers in place, i.e. for each row `r` you would write

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != n ; i++) {
    a[r][n+1] += a[r][i];
}
```

Similarly, you would compute the product (don't forget to start it with the initial value of `1`, not `0`).

At the end you would print an (m+1)×(n+1) matrix to complete the task.

Answer (score 0):

Solution : use this kind of functions for your array after making it global.

```
    void Adder(int row, int colum)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row - 1; i++)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < colum - 1; j++)
        {
            temp += a[i][j]; // added all other than last one
        }
        a[i][j] = temp; // assigned to last one in row
    }

}

void Mul(int row, int colum)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < colum- 1; i++)
    {
        int temp = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < row - 1; j++)
        {
            temp *= a[j][i]; // multiplied all element other than last one
        }
        a[j][i] = temp; // assigned to last one in column
    }

}
```